# Speeding up calculation of beta Pert distribution in Python

Tags: python, distribution

I am calculating a beta PERT distribution for each iteration of a for loop (amongst other things, but the calculation of the distribution is what takes the most time). 
Originally coded this in R and it took way too long to do this, thus the attempt to use a faster tool.

Some of my datasets can be quite big, for example I just ran a case with 153413 cases and it still took about 8hrs in Python (better than R but still a bit long).

I am quite new to Python and wondering if there is any way to speed up such a calculation?

Example code:

```
af = lambda pmu, pmin, pmode, pmax: (pmu-pmin)*(2*pmode-pmin-pmax)/((pmode-pmu)*(pmax-pmin))
bf = lambda pmu, pmin, pmode, pmax: (pmax-pmu)/(pmu-pmin)*((pmu-pmin)*(2*pmode-pmin-pmax)/((pmode-pmu)*(pmax-pmin)))

e=5.
shape=4.
max=10.
mu_d = np.arange(0, 10, 0.05)                
d = np.arange(0.025, 60.025, 0.05)
nlocs=153413  # number of rows in dataset


f0_dist = np.zeros(len(mu_d))
f1_dist = np.zeros(len(mu_d))
f2_dist = np.zeros(len(mu_d))

f0 = st.norm.cdf(d, 0.9/2., 0.9/6.)
f1 = st.uniform.cdf(d, 0.001, 0.9)

tic = time.clock()     
    for i in xrange(nlocs):
       for j in xrange(len(mu_d)): # mu_d has 121 values
            Rp_min = mu_d[j] - 1.96*e
            Rp_mode = mu_d[j] - 0.75*e
            Rp_max = max
            Rp_mu=(Rp_min+Rp_max+shape*Rp_mode)/(shape+2)
   dist = st.beta.cdf(d, a=af(Rp_mu, Rp_min, Rp_mode, Rp_max), b=bf(Rp_mu, Rp_min, Rp_mode, Rp_max), loc=Rp_min, scale=1-Rp_min)

    f0_dist[j] = 1 - np.sum(dist*f0*0.05)
    f1_dist[j] = 1- np.sum(dist*f1*0.05)
    f2_dist[j] = 1 - np.sum(dist*0.05)
    temp = 0.4*f0_dist + 0.5*f1_dist + 0.1*f1_dist
    aggr_dist = aggr_dist + temp

toc = time.clock() - tic
print '\nTime elapsed: %.3f seconds\n' % toc
```

Comment: Check indentation of the code, some pieces of code are now seen too far in left out of loop scope, where they probably belong.

Comment: @JanVlcinsky can you tell me from where did st.beta come from ??

Comment: @CodeLover No ideas. You have to ask Neodyme. As it was not fully running code, I just commented on general concepts for optimization.

Comment: @CodeLover 'import scipy.stats as st'

Comment: @Neodyme what about beta ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a bit modified code:

```
af = lambda pmu, pmin, pmode, pmax: (pmu-pmin)*(2*pmode-pmin-pmax)/((pmode-pmu)*(pmax-pmin))
bf = lambda pmu, pmin, pmode, pmax: (pmax-pmu)/(pmu-pmin)*((pmu-pmin)*(2*pmode-pmin-pmax)/((pmode-pmu)*(pmax-pmin)))

e=5.
shape=4.
max=10.
mu_d = np.arange(0, 10, 0.05)                
d = np.arange(0.025, 60.025, 0.05)

Rp_max = max
e1_96 = 1.96 * e
e0_75 = 0.75 * e
for i in xrange(nlocs): # e.g 153413
   for mu_d_j in mu_d: # mu_d has 121 values
        Rp_min = mu_d_j - e1_96
        Rp_mode = mu_d_j - e0_75
        Rp_mu=(Rp_min+Rp_max+shape*Rp_mode)/(shape+2)

   dist = st.beta.cdf(d, a=af(Rp_mu, Rp_min, Rp_mode, Rp_max), b=bf(Rp_mu, Rp_min, Rp_mode, Rp_max), loc=Rp_min, scale=1-Rp_min)
```

Explanation follows:

## Save every instructions inside of the loop

- move `Rp_max = max` out of the loop
- precaclulate constants out of loop (for `e1_96` and `e0_75`)

## Avoid deeper referencing

- do `mu_d[j]` only once and use local variable for that, getting deeper values costs time

## Use `for` looping to get the values instead of `lst[i]`

Following:

```
for j in xrange(len(mu_d)): # mu_d has 121 values
    mu_d_j = mu_d[j]
```

shall be turned into more efficient (and Pythonic):

```
for mu_d_j in mu_d: # mu_d has 121 values
    #now use mu_d_j
```

## Measure time

This is basic rule, each modification shall be evaluated.
And if you set up your expectation speed (processing time), you have chance you stop optimizing soon
enough.

## Disclaimer

As I am unable to run the code, I cannot guarantee all the changes to be correct. There are namely
few lines, which I am not sure, what they shall do:

### last line `dist =`

```
   dist = st.beta.cdf(d, a=af(Rp_mu, Rp_min, Rp_mode, Rp_max), b=bf(Rp_mu, Rp_min, Rp_mode, Rp_max), loc=Rp_min, scale=1-Rp_min)
```

Is it properly indented? As it is now, it is executed once for each `nloc` loop.

Where is the resulting `dist` value used?

If it would be part of deepest cycle, then few more optimizations could be done (using less variable
names moving some code inline).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. I wanted to keep the code relatively short for posting, but I understand some important info was missing. I have added some extra code to show mainly was I am doing with dist: I am calculating it for each iteration of i in nlocs, but just want to store the sum of all dist calculated through the loop at the end.

Comment: nlocs in just a number (the length of my data), I made a mistake when re-writing the code on here but corrected it in my post (as i in xrange(nlocs)).

Comment: As for transforming mu_d[j] in mu_d_j, this is a great idea however as you can see in my edits I am also using the 3 arrays f0_dist, f1_dist and f2_dist which are also indexed with [j]. How do I get around that?

Comment: @Neodyme Thanks for clarificatio about `nlocs`. I still miss, where you use the `i` in your code. But for me, I have no problems with it, the methods how to optimized were shown and you shall be able applying them.

Comment: By the way with my current implementation it takes 37.332 secs for nlocs=100.

Comment: @Neodyme Good to have the numbers available. You shall keep track of two thinks - the results are correct, and what time it took. Checking correctness can be achieved by comparing results with what was calculated before (to see, if optimization did not affect the results).

Comment: @JanVlcinsky can you tell me from where st.beta comes in this code ??